# Как в SDL определить загрузилась ли картинка?

Tags: sdl, c++

В `SDL` при использовании того же `SDL_Image`, при загрузке, даже если `url` не верен, не вылетает ни каких ошибок. Подскажите, пожалуйста, как проверить загрузилась ли картинка?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Судя по доке, достаточно проверить, что `IMG_Load` вернул ненулевой указатель:

> NULL is returned on errors, such as no support built for the image, or a file reading error.

Comment: Можно еще добавить вывод ошибок: ```if(texture) cout << SDL_GetError() << end;```